# Parsing a data file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a text file with two columns of data. I want to split this file and save it as two individual strings in matlab, but I also need to stop copying the data when I meet an identifier in the data then stat two new strings.

For example

H 3

7 F

B B

T Y

SPLIT

<>

Where SPLIT <> is where I want to end the current string.

I'm trying to use fopen and fscanf, but struggling to get it to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following script on the example you provided and it works. I believe the comments are very self explanatory.

```
% Open text file.
fid = fopen('test.txt');

% Read the first line.
tline = fgetl(fid);

% Initialize counter.
ii = 1;

% Check for end string.
while ~strcmp(tline, 'SPLIT')

    % Analyze line only if it is not an empty one.
    if ~strcmp(tline, '')

        % Read the current line and split it into column 1 and column 2.
        [column1(ii), column2(ii)] = strread(tline, ['%c %c']);

        % Advance counter.
        ii = ii + 1;
    end

    % Read the next line.
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

% Display results in console.
column1
column2

% Close text file.
fclose(fid);
```

The key functions here are [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) and [`strread`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/strread.html). Take a look at their documentation, it has some very nice examples as well. Hope it helps.